# Passing a parameter in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with speedometer jquery. I want to change the backgroundImage property in thisCss.

http://jsfiddle.net/8DJzW/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code on jsFiddle could never work. You're including mootools while trying to use jQuery. Just a side note

Comment: It won't work on jsfiddle no, i left out a lot of parts. That's not the problem really because everything works except how to address the backgroundImage parameter. I can address the minimum by typing minimum: 0, but how do i address and change backgroundImage?

Comment: .css('background', 'url(urlhere)');